# SwiftUI DragGesture weird jump up behavior

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, draggesture

I have created a bottom card with a drag gesture that is not yet finished. But I ran into an issue when I set the default translation height from zero and it just jumps to what I think is translation 0.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TimetableBottomCardView: View {
    @State var translation: CGSize = CGSize(width: .zero, height: 785)
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                TimetableBottomCardUI()
                Spacer()
            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Material.ultraThick)
                .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 35).ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom))
                .offset(y: translation.height)
                .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        translation = value.translation
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        withAnimation {
                            let DefaultTranslation: CGSize = CGSize(width: .zero, height: 785)
                            translation = DefaultTranslation
                        }
                    }
            )
    }
}

struct TimetableBottomCardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TimetableBottomCardView()
            .background(.blue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you rewrite your question with more explanation, images, and gifs, and with a better title/explanation, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning your transition value when your `DragGesture` changes. When you use `onChanged`, its `value` gives you a relative position, rather than an absolute one. That means your `transition` value only changes depending on where your last touch appeared, so as you're `offsetting` your view by `785`, when `onChanged` gets triggered your view jumps up due to `DragGesture`s relative value.

[image: bug]

As you can see here, your offset was 785, but when `onChanged` gets triggered, it sets it to 0, which means, it also sets its offset to zero

To avoid this behavior, you have to add your offset amount (785) to your card so that you can save your previous offset.

Result:

[image: result]

Code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TimetableBottomCardView: View {
    @State var translation: CGSize = CGSize(width: .zero, height: 785)
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Draggable Card")
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                    .background(.teal)
                Spacer()
            }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Material.ultraThick)
                .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 35).ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom))
                .offset(y: translation.height)
                .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        print(value.translation)
                        translation = CGSize(width: value.translation.width, height: value.translation.height + 785)
                    }
                    .onEnded { value in
                        withAnimation {
                            let DefaultTranslation: CGSize = CGSize(width: .zero, height: 785)
                            translation = DefaultTranslation
                        }
                    }
            )
                .onChange(of: translation) {_ in
                    // print(translation)
                }
    }
}

struct TimetableBottomCardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TimetableBottomCardView()
            .background(.blue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, use GeometryReader to push your View to the bottom. Because when you use something like 785, it is not responsive and it will be not visible on smaller devices.

Comment: I know I realised that when I tested on other devices :/

Comment: I'm Just not quite sure to how to do so.

Comment: You can open a new question like `Offsetting View to the bottom responsively in SwiftUI`

Comment: I will I will just finish everything else first so nothing interferes when I add it.